# Formatting a text to have a circular shape

Tags: svg, text, formatting, geometry

How can I use svg to format a word or small text (for example a name in a data file like .json) in a circle or sphare shape like the following image :

[image: Sphare word 2]

Comment: You can't with SVG, it does not support non-affine transforms. You could draw each letter as a path but the letters are then just paths, not formatted text.

Comment: I'm coding with d3.js , how can I do it with another tool ?

Comment: the easiest way would be to use an SVG editor, draw what you want as paths and then convert those path to d3.js if you want or just leave them as markup.

Comment: I designed a tree using D3, so I would like to put in each node a name (in a circular ship) insteed of a small circle with a text in the right or in the left side, how can I do it?